# Why fullScreenCover always take first index from array?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

Why fullScreenCover always take just first index of an array?

This is some example of code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var isFullScreen: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<5, id:\.self) { number in
                VStack{
                Text("\(number)")
                    .background(.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(20)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isFullScreen.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFullScreen) {
                    test2View(title: number)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of test2View:

```
struct test2View: View {
    var title:Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(title)")
    }
}
```

Whenever I click on any number it always show just 0, but when I make navigationLink instead of fullScreenCover, it works as expected, but navigationLink isn't a solution for my problem, I want that to be fullScreenCover.

Comment: Does `.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFullScreen) { [number] in` work?

Comment: Nope, but I realised that I can use item instead of ispresented and then { item in

Comment: Yep -- that's generally the safer way to go. Generally, you also want to move `.fullScreenCover` outside of your `ForEach` as well.

Comment: If you have found an answer, you can answer the question and accept it, or, edit the question and provide your workaround while someone can come with an explanation to or original query.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `fullScreenCover` is using a single `isFullScreen` for each number so only the first one works. Fix by adding a third intermediary `View` to hold an `isFullScreen` bool for each number, e.g.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<5) { number in
                TestView2(number: number)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView2: View {
    let number: Int
    @State private var isFullScreen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number, format: .number)")
            .background(.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(20)
            .onTapGesture {
                isFullScreen.toggle()
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFullScreen) {
                TestView3(number: number)
            }
    }
}

struct TestView3: View {
    let number: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number, format: .number)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using .fullScreenCover item parameter like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var isFullScreen: Int? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<5, id:\.self) { number in
                VStack{
                Text("\(number)")
                    .background(.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(20)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isFullScreen = number
                    }
                }
                .fullScreenCover(item: $isFullScreen) { item in
                    test2View(title: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```